# ASP.NET Core 3.1: OpPostAsync: Return an object

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to return a complex object or a Page with the object as a vide model on an OpPostAsync method? I'm talking about returning something like a PDF...

For example,, below code works:

```
public ComplexObject CObject{get;set;}
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string inputParam){
    var obj = await GetCObject(inputParam);
    CObject = obj;
    return Page();
}
myview.cshtml:

@model ComplexObject
@*Display Complex Object *@
```

Can I accomplish something similar in my OpPostAsync method?

Comment: You might want FileResult or one of its variants.  Check out these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @NickAcosta, could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to return a file such as a PDF.  Instead of returning `Page()`, return a variant of `FileResult()` instead.

A few options are:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.PhysicalFileResult
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.VirtualFileResult
```

You can read more about the differences between these result types here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0